# Non-commutative Fourier transform

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis

What is a good reference for introducing non-commutative fourier transform for Electrical Engineers and Theoretical Computer Scientists in an explicit way?

Comment: What do you mean by non-com. FT ? Expansion by group characters or matrix elements ? What is the use of this in EE ? 

Comment: I join Alexander's petition for clarification. Unless representation theory is studied in EE, the question is not very clear to me.

Comment: @Juan Representation Theory is useful in coding theory (space time codes)

Comment: I think representation theory of finite groups is exactly what's needed. For some strange reason the actual Fourier transform formulas are never given (e.g. in Serre's book)

Comment: @Igor what is use of finite groups in EE ? I worked in RT before and now work in EE (wireless com.), I would be happy to know the connections, but do not know.

Comment: @Alexander Cherov http://www.springerlink.com/content/mwgatjv3amy7y0nh/ This is open problem for general n. If you want to earn money money through math, this is one way.

Comment: @Igor Rivin: I happen to get some allergy if I see books that are not explicit. I agree representation theory of finite groups is whats needed. If there is something that is explicit with worked out examples, it will help a lot. I am also interested in applications to incidence algeras to see which cases one can convert convolution product to schur product.

Comment: an allegry that affects only guinea pigs

Comment: @unknown thank you! I also do not like non explicit things, my colleagues physicists who influenced me much always told if there is no explicit formula it is not good science....

Comment: @Alexander I am unsure of that. I just am not trained in their language.

Answer (score 8):

I think that "Group representations in probability and statistics" by Persi Diaconis is a very good choice.  It is really intended for non-algebraists and is well motivated by real world examples.  And it is available for free at [project Euclid](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/institute-of-mathematical-statistics-lecture-notes-monograph-series/Group-representations-in-probability-and-statistics/toc/10.1214/lnms/1215467407).

You could also try my [book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4614-0776-8) which is intended for a 4th year math undergrad or first year grad course and addresses some applications (sorry to plug my own book).  It is very explicit (you won't see the word module).

Answer (score 5):

I think the book [Engineering Applications of Noncommutative Harmonic Analysis](http://books.google.com/books/about/Engineering_Applications_of_Noncommutati.html?id=o9wArx_zIsEC) by Chirikjian and Kyatkin might be exactly what you are looking for.  Although I haven't read very much of it, the sections that I have read are very nice and seem mathematically rigorous, yet geared toward applications.

Also, there are a couple of excellent books by Myoung An and Richard Tolimieri about harmonic analysis over finite groups.  The first is called [Time-Frequency Representations](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0817639187), and it's about harmonic analysis over finite **abelian** groups with applications to audio signal processing.  The second is called [Group Filters and Image Processing](http://www.psypher.org/books-GFIP.html), and it's about harmonic analysis over finite **nonabelian** groups with applications to image processing.  I can't say enough about these books.  The mathematical presentation is rigorous and elegant, and the applied examples are very explicit, including Matlab code and demonstrating how the authors have applied the techniques in work they have done for defense contractors.  An overview of some of the material presented in these two book appears in [this paper](http://prometheus-us.com/asi/algebra2003/papers/tolimieri.pdf).

I highly recommend the books by Tolimieri and An -- especially "Time-Frequency Representations" -- to anyone who wants to learn signal processing the "right" way.  (Incidentally, these authors have a new book called [Ideal Sequence Design in Time-Frequency Space](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0817647376), but I have not read it.)

Comment: This looks interesting.

Comment: Looks like Myong An is fromPrometheus:)

Comment: Actually, Prometheus is a company that Myoung and Richard started in order to publish their books and make them available at much more reasonable prices than the big publishers were willing to accept.

Answer (score 3):

Barry Simon's representation theory of finite and compact groups is good.

Comment: The title is actually "Representations of Finite and Compact Groups"

Comment: Hi Igor: Is the book explicit enough for a computer scientist or an EE to understand and work through to get maturity?

Comment: I think it is pretty concrete, though I have not had any guinea pigs, er, electrical engineers, to test it on.

Comment: @Igor guinea pigs nice

Comment: @Igor Is there a notion of Fourier transform in incidence algebras?

Comment: Googling "fourier transform incidence algebra" turns up a lot of stuff, much of it having to do with Radon transform (Grinberg and Feldman have some recent stuff on Radon transform on finite geometries, but theirs is not the only work).

Comment: So the regular product in incidence algebras can be converted to a schur product? (I will google)

Comment: The book seems good. However there seems to be litle explicit examples

Comment: How about this book together with Simon's? Seems to have a lot of examples? Group Representation Theory for Physicists
 By Jin-Quan Chen, Jialun Ping, Fan Wang

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you want to have a look at  Lang "$SL_2(\mathbb{R})$" - Chapter V Spherical transform and Chapter VIII Plancherel formula: His approach is a classical, global one, which is probably more digestive than an infinitesimal approach at first encounter.  Global approach means that you work only on the group (and not on its Lie algebra), and  prove everything via integral transforms, Mellin transforms and special functions, so only a little bit of advanced calculus is needed.

Comment: Would this help in non-commutative setting?

Comment: What is a non-commutative setting and by what should it help? SL(2, R) is non-commutative, and the Harish-Chandra transform (for reductive groups only) and the Plancherel theorems are the only generalization of abelian Fourier analysis, I know.

Answer (score 1):

I am responding to the question, "What is a good reference for introducing non-commutative fourier transform for Electrical Engineers"

As an introduction to the subject, electrical engineers might find  it helpful to look at the book, "Symmetries and Groups in Signal Processing", authored by me, and published by Springer.

Virendra P. Sinha

emailmvps@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

I think $\S$ 16 of the book "Elements of the Theory of Representations" by A.A. Kirillov might be relevant. In $\S$ 16 he discusses concrete examples of representations of finite groups. Thus in $\S$ 16.1 he studies basic harmonic analysis on 3-dimensional cube, and even obtains some quantitative estimates using the representation theory of the group of symmetries of the cube.